# Same fontsize for tables in document

Tags: tables, fontsize

I cannot figure out how to get the two tables below with the SAME fontsize in a document. I think that latex creates a different fontsize, because one tables has more columns. However, i cannot figure aout how to create the first table in the same small fontsize.

Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn} 
\usepackage{setspace}         
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\topmargin0.0cm   \topskip0cm
\headheight0.0cm  \headsep0.0cm
\textheight22.6cm \textwidth16.51cm
\footskip1.5cm    %\parskip0.5cm
\usepackage{longtable,tabu,}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\csvset{
    autobooktabularcenterlong/.style={
        file=#1,
        after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{*{\csv@columncount}            {c}}\csv@tablehead,
            table head=\toprule\csvlinetotablerow\\\midrule,
            late after line=\\,
            table foot=\\\bottomrule,
            late after line=\ifnumequal{\thecsvrow}{20}{\\\midrule}{\\},
            late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
        command=\csvlinetotablerow},
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\csvautobooktabularcenterlong}[2][]        {\csvloop{autobooktabularcenterlong={#2},#1}}


\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{tableNewline}{\par}
\captionsetup[longtable]{
    justification=centering,
    labelsep=tableNewline,skip=5pt
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
    \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{11}%
    \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
    \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
    \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
    \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
        \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
        \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
        \itemsep \parsep}%
    \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents*}{dataonev1.csv}
Sector Description;A in percent;B in percent;Number of C values
Technology ;2.649;4.852;5
Automobiles \& Parts ;1.143;5.072;49
Personal \& Household Goods ;0.786;2.27;4
Utilities ;0.756;3.606;51
Food \& Beverage ;0.564;2.583;7
Oil \& Gas ;0.563;4.001;53
Insurance ;0.45;5.309;25
Banks ;0.323;3.783;130
Index;0.299;2.543;158
Industrial Goods \& Services ;0.243;2.504;41
Telecommunications ;0.194;5.09;57
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{datatwov1.csv}
Sector;A in percent;B SD in percent;C in percent;D SD in percent;E in         percent;F SD in percent
Automobiles \& Parts;4.93;4.93;0.5;0.5;1.14;5.07
Banks;0.64;0.64;0.08;0.08;0.32;3.78
Basic Resources;2.9;2.9;-0.75;-0.75;-0.14;3.41
Chemicals;0.2;0.2;0;0;0.06;3.04
Construction \& Materials;;;-0.84;-0.84;-0.84;2.82
Financial Services;;;-0.25;-0.25;-0.25;1.78
Food \& Beverage;0.56;0.56;;;0.56;2.58
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1,27ex plus 0,635ex minus 0,211ex}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
    \normalsize 
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\diamond$}  % Aufzählungssymbol in Listen

\lipsum

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.9\textwidth}
        \footnotesize
        \csvautobooktabular[separator=semicolon]{dataonev1.csv}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{dataone}\label{tab:dataone}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.9\textwidth}
        \footnotesize
        \csvautobooktabularcenterlong[separator=semicolon]{datatwov1.csv}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{datatwo}\label{tab:datatwo}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you checked the meaning of `\adjustbox` with the `max width` parameter? If I understand the manual correctly, you ask LaTeX to scale the tables down if they are wider than `0.9\textwidth`.

Comment: latex never changes the font size, it would certainly never scale tables by default, you are applying scaling with adjustbox, but scaling tables is  evil and produces inconsistent looking documents, as you rightly comment.

Comment: Rather than scaling them or using `\tiny`, which will just piss people trying to read them off by making them too small, why not rotate one or other if they are too large for the text width. (Why are you not even using the entire text width?) This will make the data much easier to read - hence, people are much more likely to be happy to read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about dropping `\adjustbox` and setting the tables strictly in `\tiny`, like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[width=17cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\makeatletter
\csvset{autobooktabularcenterlong/.style={... your definition ...}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\csvautobooktabularcenterlong}[2][]{... your definition ...}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
  \tiny
  \csvautobooktabular[separator=semicolon]{dataonev1.csv}
  \captionof{table}{dataone}\label{tab:dataone}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
  \tiny
  \csvautobooktabularcenterlong[separator=semicolon]{datatwov1.csv}
  \captionof{table}{datatwo}\label{tab:datatwo}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `\tiny` font size to make the tabular material fit "as is" in the page, you run the serious risk of rendering this material well-nigh unreadable.

I suggest you (a) reorganize the header material so that it takes up less space, (b) align the numeric data on the (actual or implied) decimal markers, and (c) use the proper typographic "minus" symbol for negative numbers. In the code below, I use the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) to achieve goals (b) and (c). With these changes in place, you can easily fit the tables inside the text block *without* having to resort to font size wizardry.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,setspace,lipsum,caption,siunitx}

\topmargin0.0cm   \topskip0cm
\headheight0.0cm  \headsep0.0cm
\textheight22.6cm \textwidth16.51cm
\footskip1.5cm    %\parskip0.5cm


\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.27ex plus 0.635ex minus 0.211ex}
\setstretch{1.25}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\diamond$}  % Aufzählungssymbol in Listen

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]}
                           S[table-format=3.0] @{}}
\toprule
Sector Description & {A}       & {B}       & {Number of} \\
                   & {(in \%)} & {(in \%)} & {C Values}\\
\midrule
Technology                    & 2.649 & 4.852 &   5\\
Automobiles \& Parts          & 1.143 & 5.072 &  49\\
Personal \& Household Goods   & 0.786 & 2.27  &   4\\
Utilities                     & 0.756 & 3.606 &  51\\ 
\addlinespace
Food \& Beverage              & 0.564 & 2.583 &   7\\
Oil \& Gas                    & 0.563 & 4.001 &  53\\
Insurance                     & 0.45  & 5.309 &  25\\
Banks                         & 0.323 & 3.783 & 130\\ 
\addlinespace
Index                         & 0.299 & 2.543 & 158\\
Industrial Goods \& Services  & 0.243 & 2.504 &  41\\
Telecommunications            & 0.194 & 5.09  &  57\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{dataone}\label{tab:dataone}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2] % filler text

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{S[table-format= 1.2]}
                      *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2]}
                           S[table-format= 1.2] @{}}
\toprule
Sector & {A} & {B SD} & {C} & {D SD} & {E}  & {F SD} \\
& {(in \%)} & {(in \%)} & {(in \%)} & {(in \%)} & {(in \%)} & {(in \%)}\\
\midrule
Automobiles \& Parts      & 4.93 & 4.93 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 1.14 & 5.07\\
Banks                     & 0.64 & 0.64 & 0.08 & 0.08 & 0.32 & 3.78\\
Basic Resources           & 2.9 & 2.9 & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.14 & 3.41\\
Chemicals                 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0.06 & 3.04\\
Construction \& Materials &  &  & -0.84 & -0.84 & -0.84 & 2.82\\
Financial Services        &  &  & -0.25 & -0.25 & -0.25 & 1.78\\
Food \& Beverage          & 0.56 & 0.56 &  &  & 0.56 & 2.58\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{datatwo}\label{tab:datatwo}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```